# Tracking system database structure

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am creating a simple customer support tracking system with PHP/MySQL

Functions are followings.

1. An admin can CRUD an customer.
2. An admin can add points/credits.: 60points (60min) etc.
3. An admin can enter the work details, date, time duration, points and display these and point(time) remaining.

The question is how to structure the tables.

I have the customer table which is the easiest part.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `web_customer` (
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `customer_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `post_code` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

I am hoping someone gives me good suggestion or examples or resources.

Comment: "good suggestion or examples or resources" - for what? Are you asking for database design resources, or asking for help with your other tables? Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is (one of) your first forays into relational database design.  I would suggest a book:  Pro SQL Server 2000 Database Design by Louis Davidson [(Here is is on Amazon)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590593022).  The implementation details are specific to SQL Server 2000, but the entire first half of the book is a great, easy to understand tutorial of relational database design; it covers how to make your design reflect your requirements, every Normalization rule, Denormalization, and the best ways to go about designing your database before even touching a computer.  Its also relatively short, so you can get to designing pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce another tables. Security table, admin table, and job table, which will relate to the customer table. I suggest you learn relational database first, and then design models for your need.